# Nodes returned from a RestCypherEngine execution produces just urls

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

When executing queries on a standalone Neo4J server using the RestCypherEngine, what is the best practice to retrieve a collection of nodes?

I have this code snippet running....

```
public DbService() {
    gd = new RestGraphDatabase("http://neo4jbox:7474/db/data/");
    engine = new RestCypherQueryEngine(gd.getRestAPI());
}

public String testData() {
    try (Transaction tx = gd.beginTx()) {
        QueryResult<Map<String, Object>> result;
        result = engine.query(
                "match (n:Person{username:'jomski2009'}) return n ",
                null);
        Iterator<Map<String, Object>> itr = result.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Map<String, Object> item = itr.next();
            log.info(item.get("n"));
        }

        tx.success();

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following result...

```
services.DbService   : http://neo4jbox:7474/db/data/node/177
```

which is a link to the node rather than the node itself. Now I know that if I return just a subset of the properties of the node in the same query that works well. What I'd like to know is how do I retrieve complete node object without necessarily specifying the properties in the query?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just the to-string representation of a RestNode, it still has the properties. But not the relationships fetched those will be fetched on demand.

I would recommend to try to fetch primitive values over the wire with Cypher, works best as it minimizes the transferred data and you only get what you need.